# Ionic ion-datetime element validation and property change

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, ionic-framework

I want to add some validation to Ionic `ion-datetime` element, I have this code.

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label>Birth of Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="1940" max="{{lastYear | date:'yyyy'}}">
        </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

And i want set this field inside a form has to be required field. And i want this max year should be 16 years lower than current year (-16)

I have been trying this so far but it is not worked

```
lastYear = null;
this.lastYear = new Date('yyyy');
```

i tried to deduct -16 from this but give me error like

> Cannot read property 'year' of null

Some one can give me proper way to do this 2 validation.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. i want set this field inside a form has to be required field.

Add a formgroup to that component and in that formgroup declare the form control name for date and time and declare that as a required one like the below example

```
public holidayForm: FormGroup; 

constructor public fb: FormBuilder){

this.holidayForm = fb.group({
  'holiday_date': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
});
}
```

when u submit the form check weather the form is valid or not if it is valid then submit if not then show required message in your app.

2.i want this max year should be 16 years lower than current year (-16)

```
 this.currentTime = new Date();
 this.year = this.currentTime.getFullYear();
 this.year = this.year - 16;
```

try using this hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: okay sir, i have some problem here i already have include DatePicker to app.module.ts file like this " imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, DatePicker, ReactiveFormsModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ], " but when i run this i got some error like Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'DatePicker' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: and i have set year variable inside the form <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/YYYY" formControlName="dob" pickerFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="1940" max="{{year}}"> and i give formControlName to this ion-datetime element it is fine?

Comment: could you participate to here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-datepicker-for-form/142006/8 here i can explain my question well. :)